# SQL server creating a virtual table or view from a table column fields

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following table.

```
EmploeeID | SalaryMonth | Basic | HRA | TravAllowance | Bonus |

1---------| May-2014 ---| 1000  | 500 --| 100 -------------| 200 ---|
```

Now I want to create a virtual table or view which has following format.

```
EmployeeID         | SalaryMonth  | SalaryType ...........| Amount


1..................| May-2014.....| Basic..................| 1000

1..................| May-2014.....| HRA....................|  500

1..................| May-2014.....|TravAllowance...........| 100

1..................| May-2014.....| Bonus..................| 200
```

How should I create a stored procedure to return above virtual or temporary table.

Comment: Any concrete problem? Do you understand how views work? That's a prerequisite for this question.

Comment: PLease mark answers to your questions in case you get a solution..

Comment: Also are the number of columns static to 4 or they might increase / decrease over a period of time? becuase in second case you will need a dynamic query..

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the Unpivot function.

See following example:

```
create table tempTable (
  EmployeeID int
, SalaryMonth date
, Basic money
, HRA money
, TravAllowance money
, Bonus money
)

insert into tempTable (EmployeeID, SalaryMonth, Basic, HRA, TravAllowance, Bonus)
values (1, '01-04-2014', 1000, 500, 100, 200)


select
  EmployeeID
, SalaryMonth
, SaleryType
, Amount
from (
   select
     EmployeeID
   , SalaryMonth
   , Basic
   , HRA
   , TravAllowance
   , Bonus
   from tempTable
) p
UNPIVOT (Amount FOR SaleryType in (Basic, HRA, TravAllowance, Bonus)
) as unpvt
```